# NGINX session based redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, nginx

I have set up two Rails applications `X` and `Y` , `X` uses session based authentication. Both applications serve the same pages. I want to setup an NGINX redirection such that if the user is logged in user gets redirected to application `X`, otherwise application `Y`.

I don't mind moving the redirect to Rails middleware level as well if something like this is not doable on NGINX level.